# How do I test logic in DDD Command handlers?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I am trying to learn some of the ideas of DDD and Clean Architecture and I came across a problem: how do I unit test Command Handlers that live in the Application Layer, verifying they call the right methods on domain objects, without testing the logic within those domain objects?
Let's say I have the following domain entity:

```
public class User
{
    public User(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public void RemoveProfilePicture()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And I have the following simple Command class:

```
public class RemoveUserProfilePictureCommand : ICommand
{
    public RemoveUserProfilePictureCommand(int userId)
    {
        UserId = userId;
    }
    public int UserId { get; }
}
```

And a Command Handler (located in the Application Layer):

```
public class Handler : ICommandHandler<RemoveUserProfilePictureCommand>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    public Handler(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(RemoveUserProfilePictureCommand command)
    {
        var user = userRepository.GetById(command.UserId);
        user.RemoveProfilePicture();
    }
}
```

I would like to verify that a call to `Handle` will find the right `User` and call the domain method `RemoveProfilePicture` on it. The only two options I found do not satisfy me and I am looking for a better solution.

### Asserting Based on the Side Effects of the Domain Logic

The obvious solution is to assert that the action on the domain model occurred, something like:

```
[Fact]
public void Handle_UserExists_ShouldRemoveProfilePicture()
{
    var user = new User(id: 555);
    repository.GetById(user.Id).Returns(user);
    var command = new RemoveUserProfilePictureCommand(user.Id);

    handler.Handle(command);

    Assert.Null(user.ProfilePicture);
}
```

The problem I have with this approach is that we make the assertions based on the logic inside the domain model, and if that logic was more complex than setting the `ProfilePicture` property to `null` we would still have to assert its results in the tests of the Command Handler, even though the domain logic is already covered by its own unit tests. The problem arises from the tight coupling of the Application Layer classes to the Domain classes. Which led me to the second solution:

### Decoupling the Application Layer from the Domain Layer

If the `User` class would implement an interface, say `IUser`, then the fake repository in the test could return a different implementation of `IUser` to the Command Handler that verifies the correct method was called. The problem here is that from my understanding, the Application Layer should be a thin wrapper around the domain and should not be decoupled from it. Also, all the examples I found always used concrete types for Domain Objects, and it does seem odd to implement an interface in an entity class.

---

Can anybody see a better solution for testing such classes? because it's not about some edge case, it's about almost every Command Handler class, and most of them are more complex than the simple example I gave above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same question when I was doing a DDD inspired CQRS project as well. From what I gather, you are also trying to develop a CQRS project since you are using concepts such as commands and are adamant about returning a `null` value in your command handler.

With that said, asserting a `null` value is not testing anything. What you are trying to test is that a side-effect has occurred in the system. In your case, you want to ensure that "a user profile picture has been removed".

What you seem to be missing is the other half of CQRS: events. When a command handler succeeds with its transaction (i.e. side-effect), you would typically dispatch an event that would represent that. Your unit tests would then simply assert that a `UserProfilePictureRemoved` event was dispatched (or enqueued, depending on your implementation).

Comment: Events are not "the other half of CQRS". CQRS can be used in conjunction with Event Sourcing or not.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I took an assumption they were using event sourcing technique and I guess I was accidentally correct. If they were not using event sourcing, then the correct answer should have been to inject mock classes/functions and seeing whether or not they have been correctly triggered. In the case of ES, we're evaluating if an event was dispatched or if the dispatch function was called with the correct event

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Handle(RemoveUserProfilePictureCommand command)
{
    var user = userRepository.GetById(command.UserId);
    user.RemoveProfilePicture();
}
```

My preferred answer: test it by having a second reviewer sign off on the claim that "the code is so simple there are obviously no deficiencies", then leave it alone.  Seriously, how many times are you expecting to refactor these two lines?  How many of those refactorings won't be automatic?

Second possibility is to add another layer of indirection; instead of having the handler work directly with the repository and the entity, instead work one layer out, expressing the protocol in terms of things that you *can* easily mock.  So you have a wrapper around the repository, and the wrapper fetches the model's user from the "real repository" and wraps that user in another mockable object.

In effect, this part of the code treats the domain model as though it were an external dependency... which of course it is (from the perspective of the handler).

It's a trade: you get to keep the domain model closed, while reducing the amount of untested interesting code, but the number of pieces required goes up.  There's also some risk of going overboard, which can lead to "test driven design damage".

The extra layer of indirection can work for you or against you when the API of the domain model is unstable.

There are lots of other variations of "add more stuff", but the trade-offs are effectively unchanged: you get more coverage, complexity goes up, you increase maintenance risks.

Option #3: As you noted, you can test the changes to the domain model.  You end up with a "sociable" test instead of a "solitary" test.

One variation that sometimes helps to keep the tests stable is to ensure that the assertions are expressed in the calculus of the domain model itself.  In effect, you have one user entity that acts as the control, and the other is your measurement, and then you ask the domain model to compare the two.

But again, notice that we are introducing more complicating elements to cover some really obvious code.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is use *stated based testing* on the domain classes, as you have done.

When it gets to the integration/application concerns I typically use *interaction based testing* and I'm not concerned with the state unless it assists in determining whether the interaction passed.  Instead of checking the state I would ask my mocking framework whether a particular call had been made.

For truly simple scenarios as you have shown I don't think I'd bother though.  Should I be specifically required to do so for the sake of code coverage then I probably would but for my own projects I probably would not :)

Comment: What do you mean by "asking the mocking framework"? Should I mock the domain entity? That would require all entities to implement interfaces. (Also, the example I gave was intentionally simple, I am trying to solve this for more complicated scenarios as well)

Comment: Mocking frameworks typically have some way to verify that a call was made.  In your case I would mock `IUserRepository`, then invoke the handler using this mocked repository, then verify that `GetById` had been called with the correct parameters.  I wouldn't recommend that an entity implements an interface other than for some role-specific scenario related to your domain.

Comment: That is possible because the repository implements an interface, my struggle is about asserting that a call was made to an entity, that cannot be replaced with a mock. How do I verify calls like `RemoveProfilePicture()`?

Comment: If you already test your domain code it shouldn't strictly be necessary but if you really want to then the sample code you have given would work just fine.  In fact, in some instances you may want to check the result of some more complex processing in which case you'll have a mixture of state- and interaction-based testing.

Comment: Why isn't it necessary? The whole purpose of a command handler is to call the right domain methods. The solution I have (that checks the state) tests mostly the logic in the domain layer, so I am looking for a way just to make sure the call was made, which is the logic of the handler. Imagine for example that there is a boolean property in the command and the handler calls different methods based on that field. How do I assert these calls?

Comment: You have to be pragmatic about those scenarios.  Use the state as you have then; else you are going to be implementing code that exists purely for the sake of testing which probably isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the idea of DDD is to use the same logic in implementation as is used in business. Make it explicit, make it visible and avoid the logical mismatch between the business and the software.

What is a command? It is an intent to change the state of a domain (data). An intent, that can be either accepted and executed, or rejected.

Acceptance and rejection is making up a decision. It can be implemented as a pure logic, in a functional way. It may be quite complex logic (think about a loan application, for example). But testing a pure logic is straightforward. This logic obviously belongs to the domain. By "straightforward" I mean that pure logic doesn't have any side effects and given the same inputs always produces the same outputs. So, testing is table-based. You just call it with some arguments and assert an output.

But then you need to prepare the data for making up a decision. And next you should execute it. This is an application logic.

By preparing the data I mean going to a database, to a storage, to configuration parameters, to external services. Most likely you need to know the current state of the domain. You need authorisation details. You need to know any additional details that could affect the decision. All this happens at the component boundary. It is not complex, mostly just accessing the read models, so you just mock integrations and verify that they are called with the correct parameters.

Executing a decision also happens at the boundary. It means updating the domain data and, maybe, notifying some third parties. Testing approach is the same as for the data preparation step. You mock an integration and verify parameters.

Of course, an integration implementations should be tested separately. Like SQL queries, HTTP interactions, reading and writing files... But that was not a part of your question, I suppose.

The difficulty with DDD is that it is hard to demonstrate on a simplistic example. In such cases it is most likely not needed. If you just update an image - what is the domain logic then? On the other hand, if you have an experience in some business domain - it would be quite easy to come up with a realistic example. But if you don't know the domain - usually any use case looks like CRUD.

From the top of my head... Think about about registering registering a real estate purchase contract. As an input you have a suit of documents. Then a specialist integrates with some systems to make sure that all the data in the documents is valid. It then checks if the property is eligible for the contract. Then a decision is the right of ownership. Or a rejection. Next, when decision is made up, all the necessary records in the state registries are made, keys transferred and so on...

You can ask then, what's the difference between such DDD and business processes that are run by business process engines? The difference is mostly about the timespan and a number of decision-making steps. In DDD all the flow happens within hundreds of milliseconds. There is a single decision-making step. No intermediate persisted state - all is stored in memory. While a business process may take days and weeks. And may involve multiple decision-making, data-preparation, execution and conditional branching.